# how to change the default user name in Visual C++ Express Edition?

Tags: visual-c++

I have started to use Visual C++ 2008 Express Edition and I notice that when one makes a project it appears something like this (in the folder's projects):

myFirstProgram.vcproj.Little-PC.Little.user

I would like to change the part where it appears my user name, is there any part inside the Visual C++ IDE where I can do that? I have been looking around, but found nothing at all.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is VS **project user options** file, so it is linked with the user account under which the project was opened. [Seems you cannot change this.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e2e24de2-580d-40fb-ad44-632aca1d0583/how-to-make-visual-studio-stop-creating-user-options-file?forum=vcgeneral) This file stores per-user debugging settings for the project.

Real source code project settings are in myFirstProgram.vcproj.